# Single persistent TCP connection for server to server connection

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, tcp

I have to implement a server to server communication protocol using a SINGLE PERSISTENT TCP connection. The server at both the ends of this connection are implemented using "multi-threaded and asynchronous event-driven model". Both these servers are implemented in C++ and Pthreads on Linux. Server A always sends requests to Server B and Server B responds with a response. Server B doesn't send any requests to Server A, it just responds to the requests it receives. Could some one post me a sample code for this communication? Could you help me with the code for both Server A and Server B? Or please point me to any old answers or any websites where i can find a prototype code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it clearly, sorry my bad. Both Server A and Server B are application servers talking a custom protocol. So please ignore the term "TCP Server". But the connection between them is a persistent TCP connection

Answer (score 1):

TCP servers cannot open connections to TCP servers.  There is no IP protocol for that.  One of the two servers must run a TCP client as a subsystem.  The exact mechanics of how you do that depend on your client<>server protocol  - the 'server-client' could log in to the 'client-server' with a unique username/password, or could use a different server listening port.

It's up to you:)